# Second variation formula in differential geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, calculus-of-variations

One can compute the second variation for both energy and length.
There is a factor different in ther intergration term. 
$h(s,t)$ is the (proper) variation,  $\forall t, h(0,t)=c(t)$, and let $Y=D_{(0,t)}h(\partial_s)$. 
In the second variation for length and engergy, the term mostly coincide.
Except for a term in the intergral, while the second variation for energy is $Y$, but length is $Y^\perp$ (components perpendicular to $c'$).

But on the other hand, if it is unit geodesic, also wlog assume b-a=0.5 then $L=\sqrt{E}$. So $L'=\frac{E'}{\sqrt{E}}$, $L''=\frac{E''\sqrt{E}-\frac{E'^2}{2\sqrt{E}}}{E}$. Because E'=0, and $E$ is fixed, $L''$ is kinda porpotional to $E''$. However, it is not. Why is it like that?

Comment: What do you mean by "$E$ is fixed"? $E$ has a stationary point (need not even by minimal), but if you change the path then $E$ will change (at second order level), as will $L$.

Comment: Eventually, we evaluate at s=0. so it is a just a value.

Comment: But for a statement like $E$ is proportional to $L$ it does not make sense to fix $s=0$. And if you don't fix $s=0$, the statement is not true.

Comment: yea, kinda stupid thought I had... And it there a quick, intuitive or geometric way to see why the difference is the projection? It seems that they are related.